# Entity Framework Sum e Count diferentes status

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core

No meu projeto ASP.NET MVC, estou tentando alcançar o equivalente a esse código do SQL Server:

```
Select 
    e.Numero, 
    e.ValorEmprestimo, 
    Count(Case when pvp.IdeStatus = false and pvp.DatVencimento >= '20190710' then pvp.Id else null end) as NumParcelaAVencidaPendente,
    Sum(Case when pvp.IdeStatus = false and pvp.DatVencimento < '20190710' then pvp.ValParcela else 0 end) as TotParcelaVencidaPendente,
    Sum(Case when pvp.IdeStatus = false and pvp.DatVencimento >= '20190710' then pvp.ValParcela else 0 end) as TotParcelaAVencerPendente,
    Sum(Case when pvp.IdeStatus = true then pvp.ValParcela else 0 end) as TotParcelaPaga
From 
    Emprestimo e
    Inner Join Parcela pvp On (pvp.EmprestimoId = e.Id)
GROUP By e.Numero
Order by e.Id
```

Dados

```
    Empréstimo
    Id  Valor
    2   200000.0

    Parcela    
    DatVencimento ValParcela    EmprestimoId    IdeStatus
    05/07/2019    20165.37      2               1
    05/08/2019    20165.37      2               0
    05/09/2019    20165.37      2               0
    05/10/2019    20165.37      2               0
    05/11/2019    20165.37      2               0
    05/12/2019    20165.37      2               0
    05/01/2020    20165.37      2               0
    05/02/2020    20165.37      2               0
    05/03/2020    20165.37      2               0
    05/04/2020    20165.37      2               0
```

Resultado
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Usando o Entity Framework, em única consulta, como trazer as linhas com os empréstimos e as colunas os valores somado das parcelas de acordo com o seu status? É possível trazer em um única chamada e obter o mesmo resultado ou neste caso deve proceder usando uma procedure no lado do SQL?

Answer (score 1):

Se as tabelas Emprestimo e Parcela estão bem relacionadas:

```
var data = new DateTime(2019, 7, 10);

var result = conn.Emprestimo
    .Select(e => new
    {
         e.Id,
         e.Numero,
         e.ValorEmprestimo,
         e.Parcela.IdeStatus,
         e.Parcela.ValParcela,
         e.Parcela.DatVencimento
    }
    .OrderBy(e => e.Id)
    .GroupBy(e => e.Numero, (num, list) => new
    {
         Numero = num,
         ValorEmprestimo = list.First(o => o.ValorEmprestimo),
         NumParcelaAVencidaPendente = list.Count(o => !o.IdeStatus && o.DatVencimento >= data),
         TotParcelaVencidaPendente = list.Sum(o => !o.IdeStatus && o.DatVencimento < data),
         TotParcelaAVencerPendente = list.Sum(o => !o.IdeStatus && o.DatVencimento >= data),
         TotParcelaPaga = list.Sum(o => o.IdeStatus)
    }
    .ToArray();
```